# How I get tweet's date-time from Twitter with Selenium with class name

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape Twitter content with Selenium but I have issues about date time.

This is what I tried. I can get a text with this but date_span stays None and I get "'NoneType' object is not callable" error.

```
for li in soup.find_all("li", class_='js-stream-item'):

    text_p = li.find("p", class_="tweet-text")
    if text_p is not None:
        tweet['text'] = text_p.get_text()

        date_span = li.find("a", class_="tweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip")
        tweet['created_at'] = date_span.get_attribute('title')
```

```
<small class="time">
  <a href="/crypto2bigbang/status/1114844247700586496" 
class="tweet-timestamp js-permalink js-nav js-tooltip" 
title="3:55 AM - 7 Apr 2019" data-conversation-id="1114844247700586496">
<span class="_timestamp js-short-timestamp js-relative-timestamp" data-time="1554634556" data-time-ms="1554634556000" 
data-long-form="true" aria-hidden="true">2m</span>
<span class="u-hiddenVisually" data-aria-label-part="last">2 minutes ago</span></a>
</small>
```

I want to get date time like  "3:55 AM - 7 Apr 2019" which is in "title".

This is my first question here. I hope it is proper :)

Comment: this time is in epoch all you need is to convert it using `datetime` module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import time,datetime
date_span = soup.find("span",class_="_timestamp js-short-timestamp js-relative-timestamp")
print(time.strftime('%H:%M %p-%d %B %Y',  time.gmtime(float(date_span))))
```

this will give the time `10:55 AM-07 April 2019` you can learn more about formatting here [strftime documentaion](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)